# Python IndexError: Out of bounds

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I've created a class of which I pass an image (2D array, 1280x720). It's suppose to iterate through, looking for the highest value:

```
import bumpy as np

class myCv:
    def maxIntLoc(self,image):
        intensity = image[0,0]  #columns, rows
        coordinates = (0,0)
        for y in xrange(0,len(image)):
            for x in xrange(0,len(image[0])):
                if np.all(image[x,y] > intensity):
                    intensity = image[x,y]
                    coordinates = (x,y)
        return (intensity,coordinates)
```

Yet when I run it I get the error:

```
if np.all(image[x,y] > intensity):
IndexError: index 720 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 720
```

Any help would be great as I'm new to Python.

Thanks,
Shaun

Comment: Should it be `image[x, y]` or `image[y, x]`?

Comment: Why are you iterating through the entire image? Have you considered using vectorisation instead?

Comment: @PouriaHadjibagheri Thanks for your comment, I'm now looking into vectorisation.

Comment: I'm writing an example for you. Wait a few minutes. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, like most programming languages, indexes start at `0`.

So you can access only pixels from `0` to `719`.

Check with a debug print that `len(image)` and `len(image[0])` are indeed returning 1280 and 720.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the index error that you are experience, which has been addressed by others, iterating through pixels/voxels is not a valid method for manipulating images. The issue becomes particularly evident in multi-dimensional images, where you face the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality).

The correct way to do this is to use vectorisation in programming languages that support it (e.g. Python, Julia, MATLAB). Through this method, you will achieve the results you're looking for much more efficiently (and thousands of times faster). [Click here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_programming) to find out more about vectorisation (aka. array programming). In Python, this can be achieved either using generators, which are not suitable for images as they don't really produce the results until called; or using `NumPy` arrays.

Here is an example:

## Masking image matrices by vectorisation

```
from numpy.random import randint
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, imshow, title, grid, show

def mask_img(img, thresh, replacement):
    # Copy of the image for masking. Use of |.copy()| is essential to 
    # prevent memory mapping.
    masked = initial_image.copy()

    # Replacement is the value to replace anything that 
    # (in this case) is bellow the threshold. 
    masked[initial_image<thresh] = replacement  # Mask using vectorisation methods.

    return masked

# Initial image to be masked (arbitrary example here).
# In this example, we assign a 100 x 100 matrix of random integers 
# between 1 and 256 as our sample image. 
initial_image = randint(0, 256, [100, 100])  
threshold = 150  # Threshold

# Masking process.
masked_image = mask_img(initial_image, threshold, 0)

# Plots.
fig = figure(figsize=[16,9])

fig.add_subplot(121)
imshow(initial_image, interpolation='None', cmap='gray')
title('Initial image')
grid('off')

fig.add_subplot(122)
imshow(masked_image, interpolation='None', cmap='gray')
title('Masked image')
grid('off')

show()
```

Which returns:

[image]

Of course you can put the masking process (function) in a loop to do this on a batch of images. You can modify the indices and do it on 3D, 4D (e.g. MRI), or 5D (e.g. CAT scan) images too, without the need to iterate over each individual pixel or voxel.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're very welcome. It makes life much more easier (and faster) for analysing images. By the way, if you want to convert an already existing variable to vector, you can use `numpy.array`.